# WP Query causing timeout

Tags: wp-query

Im trying to show taxonomy names along with their counts for a donut-chart. This is what im doing;

```
<ul class="pie-chart__legend" id="donut1">
<?php
$wcatTerms1 = get_terms('incident_type', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
foreach($wcatTerms1 as $wcatTerm1) 
{

$args1 = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'incident',
'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'incident_type',
'field' => 'term_id', 
'terms' => $wcatTerm1, 
'include_children' => false
)
));
$count1 = 0;
$query1 = new WP_Query($args1);
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) 
{ 
$count1++;
}
?>
<li><em><?php echo $wcatTerm1->name; ?></em><span><?php echo $count1; ?></span></li>
<?php
}    
?>
```

But this is running infinite and eventually timing out. I tried several fixies involving the_posts() but not working.

Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out. I was missing `$query1->the_post();` in the while loop and `wp_reset_postdata();` after the loop ends.

Final working code:

```
<ul class="pie-chart__legend" id="donut1">
                                    <?php
                                    $wcatTerms1 = get_terms('incident_type', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
                                    foreach($wcatTerms1 as $wcatTerm1) 
                                    {
                                        
                                        $args1 = array(
                                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                        'post_type' => 'incident',
                                        'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'incident_type',
                                                'field' => 'term_id', 
                                                'terms' => $wcatTerm1, 
                                                'include_children' => false
                                            )
                                        ));
                                        $count1 = 0;
                                        $query1 = new WP_Query($args1);
                                        while ( $query1->have_posts() ) 
                                        { 
                                            $query1->the_post();
                                            $count1++;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <li><em><?php echo $wcatTerm1->name; ?></em><span><?php echo $count1; ?></span></li>
                                        <?php
                                        wp_reset_postdata();
                                    }    
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
```